# Facebook API Common Friends

Tags: api, facebook

Is it possible to get common friends using a Facebook API (the intersect of two friends lists)?

For example if you use the Facebook graph API you can do something like

https:..//graph.facebook.com/me/friends

but if you do

https:..//graph.facebook.com/220439/friends

there is a privacy error...

But if you can see the same information with

http://www.facebook.com/friends/?id=220439

So you get the privacy error using the API but the information is publicly available?

So the result is to resort to screen scraping?... Seems odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get access to a user's friends list, you need a valid access token for that user.  Then to get the intersection of two friends lists, you would need a valid access token for both users.  Retrieve the friends lists separately and then do the intersection in your own code.

As far as I know, it is not possible to get a user's friends list without an access token for that user.

Comment: I believe that is the correct answer if you're making API calls but it is possible to get the user's friends list without the access token using screen scraping.